# Create merged JSON with GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I've found tons of examples of using GSON to convert either an single object, or a list of that single object, to its respective JSON. Quite easy to do. Even if the object has objects as its properties, this still is trivial.

But let's say I have 5 objects of interest (names, companies, colors, numbers, candy) and they have no relationship to each other at all. So I make my database calls, and now have 5 lists full of all of the above in my code.

Now, how could I put these lists into a JSON Array whose parent name is "items" and contains all of the above as children beneath it? So one parent "items", with 5 children (each child is a sibling of each other).

What is the appropriate way using GSON (or not??) to construct such a tree or structure?
I noticed there is a lot in GSON such as JSONArray and such, but wasn't able to figure it out.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please clarify. My understanding is that you want to encapsulate all the data into one JSON object. It seems like creating a custom serializer may be the solution.

Comment: Post your JSON String first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. You have to build your own serializer first. For instance:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public static String toJson(List<Item> items){

    try{

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

        JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();

        for(Item i : items){
            JSONObject itemObj = new JSONObject();
            itemObj.put("names", i.getName());
            itemObj.put("companies", i.getCompanies());
            itemObj.put("colors", i.getColors());
            itemObj.put("numbers", i.getNumbers());
            itemObj.put("candy", i.getCandy());
            jsonArr.put(itemObj);
        }

        jsonObj.put("items", jsonArr);

        return jsonObj.toString();

    } catch(JSONException ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I will try this tonight, but I suspect this will do the trick. Very concise too. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, no problem! I just edited my code because I forgot to add one line at the end of the `for` loop. Be aware of it. It is really important :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the fields are, you can make a model class and set the objects from database. The use `Gson` and form your `Json` string using `jsonFrom`.

Eg.

```
public class Items{

ArrayList<String> names;

String candy;

//nested custom class if necessary
ArrayList<Companies> companies;

//other fields here 

//getter setter
}
```

Now set the values for objects of `Items`.

Then:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(modelClassObject);
```

If i got your requirement right, `json` is the String you need.

Answer (score 0):

To merge JSONs you need to define some conventions of merging. If **"Overlay" strategy (replace or add)** conforms you, you can find a *helpful JSON Merging Library* **[in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52621962/1112963)**.