# Gson - Merge multiple JSONs objects into one JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a case where I need to merge multiple JSONs objects into one JSON.
A single response looks like this:

```
{"name":"MyName"}
```

Multiple merged JSON looks like this:

```
["{\"name\":\"name\"}","{\"name\":\"MyName\"}"]
```

The problem here is that the child JSONs that I want to include can come either from a Java object or are available as String itself.

```
MyRequest request = new MyRequest();
request.setName("name");
String singleJson = new Gson().toJson(request);

String fromSomePlaceElse = "{\"name\":\"MyName\"}";;
List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList(singleJson,fromSomePlaceElse);
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(list));
```

The above gives me the following output:

```
["{\"name\":\"name\"}","{\"name\":\"MyName\"}"]
```

instead of:

```
[{"name":"MyName"}, {"name":"MyName"}]
```

I don't want to parse the already existing JSON and do the following:

```
List<MyRequest> list2 = Lists.newArrayList(request, new Gson().fromJson(fromSomePlaceElse, MyRequest.class));
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(list2));
```

Can this be done using Gson ?

Comment: How about `System.out.println(list);`?

Comment: OMG! How did I miss that ? Please post it as an answer so that I can accept .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just print it.

```
List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList(singleJson,fromSomePlaceElse);
System.out.println(list);
```

Then you can get

```
[{"name":"name"}, {"name":"MyName"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want json in form of string,you can directly use ---

```
new Gson().toJson(yourList, new TypeToken<List<JsonObject>>(){}.getType())
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the given library to **merge any amount of JSON-objects** at once. The result can be returned as `String` or `JsonObject` (GSON). Please reference the code in **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52621962/1112963)**.